# Filter tax_query in my wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know how i filters property area , i Try :

```
<?php     
                 $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'estate_property',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'tax_query'         => array(
                                                'taxonomy'  => 'property_area',
                                                'field'     => 'slug',
                                                'terms'     => 'pigalle',
                    ),
                );

            $selection = new WP_Query($args);
            ?>
```

But all show ! WHY ? lol

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up on [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

The tax_query parameter is a multi-dimensional array. You need to wrap it with another array:

```
<?php     
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'estate_property',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'property_area',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'pigalle'
        )
    )
);

$selection = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's just , i never see that, now it makes sense to me ! Thanks my friends !!!